Azure Dev-Ops - Stages and Variable Groups
I am working with an azure devops environment that I inherited, and have this problem.
I created a new stage by cloning another.  I also created a new variable group to be used by this new stage, which has target server names.
The problem I have is that when I deploy this new stage, it deploys to the original server, not the new one (as if it's still using the same old variable group).
I guess I am having difficulty associating the new stage with the proper scope?  What ties the new stage to the new variable group?
What am I missing?  (Here is my pipeline yml file)
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- develop
- release-*

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'x64'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

jobs:
- job : Backend
  pool:
    name: 'Default'
  steps:
  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '6.9.1' # string. Version of NuGet.exe to install.

  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
      feedsToUse: 'select'
      noCache: true

  - task: VSBuild@1
    displayName: 'Build Web'
    inputs:
      solution: '$(solution)'
      msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
      platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
      vsVersion: '17.0' # Optional. Options: latest, 16.0, 15.0, 17.0
      
  - task: VSTest@2
    inputs:
      testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
      testAssemblyVer2: |
        **\*test*.dll
        !**\*TestAdapter.dll
        !**\obj\**
      searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      vstestLocationMethod: 'location'
      vstestLocation: 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform'
      platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
      otherConsoleOptions: '/Platform:x64'

  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: 'Zip Service'
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/jobs/winservice/IAM.PestApp.Service/bin/$(buildConfiguration)'
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveType: 'zip'
      archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/winservice.zip'
      replaceExistingArchive: true

  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: 'Zip IAMPestAppService DB'
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: 'dbs/IAMPestAppService/bin/$(buildConfiguration)'
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveType: 'zip'
      archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/IAMPestAppService.zip'
      replaceExistingArchive: true

  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: 'Zip IAMPestApp DB'
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: 'dbs/IAMPestApp/bin/$(buildConfiguration)'
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveType: 'zip'
      archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/IAMPestApp.zip'
      replaceExistingArchive: true
      
  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: 'Zip IAMPowerBI DB'
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: 'dbs/IAMPowerBI/bin/$(buildConfiguration)'
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveType: 'zip'
      archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/IAMPowerBI.zip'
      replaceExistingArchive: true
      
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: 'Copy PBIX Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) '
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: 'src/IAM.PestApp.UI'
      Contents: '**/*.pbix'
      TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: 'Copy Azure Deploy Files To Staging Directory'
    inputs:
      Contents: |
        build/azuredeploy.json
        build/azuredeploy.parameters.json
      TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      OverWrite: true

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifact: 'IAM.PestApp.UI'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'

- job: Frontend
  pool: 
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.x' 
      addToPath: true 
      architecture: 'x64' # Options: x86, x64 (this argument applies only on Windows agents)

  - task: NodeTool@0
    displayName: Install Node.js
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '14.x'  #'Your version e.g. 14.x'

  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'NPM - Install React Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'install'
      workingDir: 'src/ui'

  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'NPM - Build React Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      workingDir: 'src/ui'
      customCommand: 'run build'

  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'NPM - Test React Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      workingDir: 'src/ui'
      customCommand: 'run testOnce'

  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: 'Zip React Project'
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: 'src/IAM.PestApp.UI/Content/COW'
      includeRootFolder: true
      archiveType: 'zip'
      archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/COW.zip'
      replaceExistingArchive: true

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifacts'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifact: 'FrontEnd'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'

Update
Here is what I see when I try to edit my pipeline, but again, this is the build pipeline:

In that view, the 'variables button only allows my set set individual variables for the pipeline.
I need to select a release before it let's me see the stages.

Here are my variable groups.  The one I am targeting is the production-flex group.


Please edit your post and share the relevant code. Are you using YAML pipelines?

Thanks for adding the pipeline code. However, I'm confused - there are 2 jobs in your pipeline and no references to variable groups?

I know, right?  These tasks drive the build.  It's the deployment process that I am confused about.

This pipeline builds and publishes the backend and frontend applications as artifacts, if I understand it correctly. There is probably another pipeline doing the deployment to the servers you mentioned using the artifacts published in the pipeline you've pasted. Your problem is in the other pipeline.

"It's the deployment process that I am confused about." - you need to show us the correspondent code.

@ruijarima, What optiona are there besides using 'YAML Pipelines'?  The only place I find stages is on the Azure DevOps UI page after selecting a release.

Now I understand your scenario. You're probably using the classic release pipelines (UI based), not YAML pipelines. Ideally you should use only YAML pipelines, the UI-based builds and releases are kind of obsolete (IMO). But anyway, I'll add another answer soon related to the classic release pipelines.

Added another answer.

Hi @JoeDerham, Good day. May I know if you have got a chance to check the answers by RUI below to reference variable groups in different scopes with YAML/release pipelines? Hope they could resolve your query in this post. Thx for the sharing.

@AlvinZhao - I am still having difficulty, but Rui seems to be helping me get on the right track.  It'll be something stupid/ignorant on my part.  :)

Upon checking your update, may I know if there is any misunderstanding on the RUI's answer? Why did you add a build YAML pipeline screenshot where you didn't reference any variable group? The variables in a build pipeline will not take effect in its subsequent release pipeline. Besides, are you sure the variable group is the cause of the failure in your new stage Production-Flex? You can add a command line task to with a script to echo $(VarInProductionFlexGroup) to verify if the variable group is correctly referenced.

You may also check the agent/group jobs that your new stage is running on. Since it could a different topic from that in this post, please feel welcome to create a new thread and share more details for further investigation. Thx and good luck with the work to go.

Regarding Azure classic release pipelines, variable groups can be managed in the Variables > Variable Groups section of the release:

Please note that the scope of a variable or variable group can be set to the entire release or, as an alternative, one or more stages:

Setting the scope:

The above applies to individual pipeline variables as well.
See Use variable groups in Classic pipelines for more details.

Thanks for all your effort, but my UI does not look like this.  I did find that I had the wrong scope associated with my VariableGroup, but that didn't help.  It looks to me like I still can't assign a scope to my stage.

@JoeDerham are you using Azure DevOps Services (cloud) or Azure DevOps Server (on-prem)? And which version? UI can't be that different. Please edit your question and post some screenshots. Maybe you can't change the scope because you don't have enough permissions?

I'll post another pick of what I am looking at.  The deployments go to on-prem machines.

@JoeDerham I meant the screenshot of the release/stage/variables section in Azure DevOps, not the target server of the deployment.

I think I figured my answer.  In the stage, there are a set of jobs.  Each job has a "deployment group" drop down.  THAT seems to have done the trick.
Duh!  Now I know.  I thought the scope was assigned at the stage level, but it is not?
Thanks so much for your help, Rui.  I really really appreciate it!

Hi @JoeDerham, That's for the update. If the answer by RUI works for you, you may consider this. Appreciate your time and efforts which may help others with similar concerns. Cheers!

@JoeDerham I just noticed your screenshots, and to be honest that's not the right approach. You should do as I mentioned in this answer otherwise you'll have to edit the variable groups every single time after you queue a new release. Edit the variable groups in the release definition instead. And next time I'd suggest you to add the relevant code and/or screenshots to your question earlier, to avoid any confusion or misunderstanding.

Thanks @RuiJarimba - You got me looking in the right direction.  I learned a lot in the process.  Thank you!  I'll consider your suggestions when time permits.  I just gotta find time.  :)

@JoeDerham if my answer helped you consider upvoting it.

@RuiJarimba - Certainly - I am debating which one would best help someone else in the future while recognizing the detail that I had missed.  You definitely get the points!

Pipeline variables scope
In a YAML pipeline you can set a variable at various scopes:

At the root level, to make it available to all jobs in the pipeline
At the stage level, to make it available only to a specific stage.
At the job level, to make it available only to a specific job.


The problem I have is that when I deploy this new stage, it deploys to the original server

I suspect you're not referencing the variable group at the right scope.
Try setting each variable group at the stage or at job level. Ideally, you should reduce the scope of your variables as much as possible.
Example:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
  - stage: ServerA
    jobs:
      - job: DeployToServerA
        variables:
          - group: server-a-variables # Use a variable group at the job level
      # ....

  - stage: ServerB
    jobs:
      - job: DeployToServerB
        variables:
          - group: server-b-variables # Use a variable group at the job level
      # ....

See Variable scopes for more details.
Pipeline variables precedence
Please note that when you set a variable with the same name in multiple scopes, the following precedence applies (highest precedence first):

Job level variable set in the YAML file
Stage level variable set in the YAML file
Pipeline level variable set in the YAML file
Variable set at queue time
Pipeline variable set in Pipeline settings UI

When you set a variable with the same name in the same scope, the last set value takes precedence.
See Expansion of variables for more details.
